# Using sed, insert a space at the 3rd last index of each line

Tags: sed

I would like to insert a space, before the 3rd last character of each line, to turn this:

```
CC287999221

CHGFFDTTT34AAA387

CH654AZ0987XX277
```

**Into this:**

```
CC287999 221

CHGFFDTTT34AAA 387

CH654AZ0987XX 277
```

**So far I've tried:**

```
sed -i 's/.*\(...\)/ \1/' file
```

However this remove the preceding text also.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
sed 's/\(...$\)/ \1/' file
```

Just match the last 3 characters, while substituting put a space and then the matched pattern(`\1`)

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` could you please try following.

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-3),substr($0,length($0)-2)}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu sed:

```
sed -E 's/\S{3}\s*$/ &/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk proposal:

```
awk '{sub(/.{3}$/," &")}1' file 
CC287999 221

CHGFFDTTT34AAA 387

CH654AZ0987XX 277
```